# Australian immigration best contact number

Tags: citizenship, telephone

Has anyone got a correct number to call for Australian citizenship enquiries? I am trying 0061 261 960196, as per the Australian website, but I keep getting the response:

> This service can not be connected.

Comment: From what country are you placing this call? Are you using a landline or a cellular connection?

Answer (score 1):

The exact number you need to dial depends on the country your are dialing from. In most countries of the world, you call an international number by dialing `00` before the country code (`61` in this case for Australia).

However, things are a bit different in the US and Canada (and some [other places](https://www.howtocallabroad.com/codes.html)), where you have to dial `011` before the country code. So if you are calling from the US or Canada, you probably need to dial `01161 261 960196`. (I have not verified the local part of the number, I've only explained how to dial that number from the US or Canada.)